# How to embed a CollectionView in a TableView?

Tags: ios, header, tableview, collectionview

I've put a `UICollectionView` in the *header* of my table, but when I test it all I see is a black rectangle where my *collection* should be. What do I have to do to be able to see it? I did some research and found a method called `viewForHeaderInSection`, but I haven't found any explanation for it so I don't even know if that is what I need or what to do with it.

An additional question would be where do I put the related methods for the *collection*? (a new file?)

If it's important, this is on an IPad screen.

Answer (score 0):

in your CellForRowAtIndexPath, add something like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
LiteratureScrollViewController* cv = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"collectionViewID"];

[cell.contentView addSubview:cv.view];
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
[cv didMoveToParentViewController:self];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by related methods? if you meant tap events you can add it to your custom collectionViewCell class..

Comment: What I mean is that I need to get information from the item that is clicked (its name) and use it in the main screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue...
Select the actual collection view inside of your view in Storyboard. Check the background color. If you change it to "Clear Color" you just might see your collection view! While testing, to see your "item", select it, and set it's color to white, or something other than the view's background color.

Answer (score 0):

In your `UICollectionView` `Class` do something like the method below to see which item was selected and then you can do whatever you want with selected object.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        [self performSelector:@selector(singleTapOnCell:) withObject:indexPath];

}
```

Comment: I've put that in and I added a print statement to test it. The method isn't being called right now. I guess I need to add a gesture recognizer in code, but where does it go? I would guess it goes in a method in the cell class that gets called at the beginning.